# Logstash reparses file if it is just renamed

Tags: logstash

I am parsing files using logstash and storing it in mongodb. I donot want logstash to reparse the file if the file is just renamed. How can i achieve this?
I included the sincedp_path field and my command is like this.

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/file.log"
        sincedb_path => "/logstash"
    }
}
output {
    mongodb {
        collection ="collect" database => "db" uri => "mongodb://localhost"
    }
}
```

**This gives the following error:**

```
A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
Error: Permission denied - /logstash.13562.1005.292789 or /logstash            {:level=>:error}
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /logstash.13562.1005.545871 or /logstash
      rename at org/jruby/RubyFile.java:987
atomic_write at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-    0.6.4/lib/filewatch/helper.rb:39
_sincedb_write at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.4/lib/filewatch/tail.rb:236
sincedb_write at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/filewatch-0.6.4/lib/filewatch/tail.rb:206
teardown at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-file-1.0.0/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:157
inputworker at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:203
synchronize at org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149
inputworker at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:203
start_input at /logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-1.5.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:171
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of logstash is to track files by inode in the sincedb.  This would handle files being renamed properly.  If you are experiencing it not working, then chances are your sincedb is set to a directory/file that logstash can't write to.  You can explicitly say where your sincedb: http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#sincedb_path

```
file {
  sincedb_path  => '/some/writable/directory'
}
```

Comment: Now my command is like this.  bin/logstash -e 'input { file { path => "/someFile.log" sincedp_path => "/logstash" } } output { mongodb { collection => "collect" database => "db" uri => "mongodb://localhost" } }' This give an error Unknown setting 'sincedp_path' for file {:level=>:error}. How can I solve this?

Comment: @user2577156: Read carefully. You have misspelled `sincedb_path`. Also, it shouldn't contain the path to a directory but to a file.

Comment: It's true that inodes are being used for tracking, but when files are renamed the old sincedb entry is deleted first so the state is actually lost. With `start_position => end` this is usually okay anyway, but with `start_position => beginning` the file will indeed be read from the beginning even though that hardly was the user's intention.

Comment: OH! My Bad :( Updated my new error in the question.

Comment: start_position => "end" is not reading a new file. So have to use "beginning" right? So is there any way so that the renamed files are not read? Also, suppose i have file named file1 containing lines A B and another file named file2 with lines A B C D and if i parse both the files, the mongodb must have only A B C D by ignoring the lines A and B of file2 as it has been already parsed and stored once.

Comment: the permission error on /logstash means that you need to create that directory and give the user that's running logstash permissions to write to it.